# SublimeText font in Windows like Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, fonts, sublimetext

For a long time wondering how to set the font in the Sublime to look like in Ubuntu (pretty, slim, smooth above all)? I downloaded the Ubuntu Mono font, but it does not look like Ubuntu. 
My config file:

```
{
    "auto_complete": false,
    "close_windows_when_empty": false,

    "folder_exclude_patterns":
    [
        ".svn",
        ".git",
        ".hg",
        "CVS",
        "_build",
        "dist",
        "build",
        "site"
    ],
    "font_face": "Ubuntu Mono Bold",
    "font_options":
    [
        "subpixel_antialias"
    ],
    "font_size": 13.0,
    "theme": "Soda Dark.sublime-theme",
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
}
```

Windows - Ubuntu Mono Bold (looks ugly)

[image: Beautiful appearance on Ubuntu]
[image: Windows:] 
Ubuntu

Ubuntu Mono in Windows

[image]

How to improve the quality and color of the display code on Windows?

Comment: Is that a bold version?

Comment: I meant you should try `Ubuntu Mono` instead of `Ubuntu Mono Bold`.

Comment: @Shomz yes, it is Bold, but only Ubuntu Mono In general, it is not similar to the photo Sublime of ubuntu that I posted.

Comment: Reduce the size and drop the bold and it should be good.

Comment: @Shomz have reduced the size, but it still looks the same. (I put the screen), any ideas?

Comment: Maybe will set another question. As in Windows, you can get the rendering of fonts such as Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh, I see now, it looks pretty bad. Sorry, no idea how do fix it except maybe trying to experiment the system-wide font settings (like clear-type, regular, etc... can't remember now, but Windows has those, or used to have).

Comment: I have all the time enabled Clear-Type in Windows.